# Google Timezone API request CORS error

Tags: javascript, angularjs, cors, preflight, google-maps-timezone

I try to request the Google Timezone API from an AngularJS app.

But when I'm making my request I got this error in the preflight request :

```
XMLHttpRequest cannot load https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/timezone/json?location=48.8709,2.3561&timestamp=14912286400&key=MY_KEY. Request header field Authorization is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Headers in preflight response.
```

Here is my Google API configuration :
[image]

I've tried to disable preflight request by setting header with `Content-Type: 'text/plain'`, but there is always a preflight request.

Do you think the error mentioned above is caused by the preflight request or do you think I should look in another direction ?

Thanks in advance

**EDIT** : I know how to enable CORS on my server, this is not the point. What I want is to access Google API from my AngularJS app without creating à WS on my server (if it's possible). If I don't have choice I'll do it, but in this case I know how to do it.

**ANSWER** :  Thanks to @Sebas I solved my problem with the `window.fetch()` API. This doesn't work on IE, but there is a great polyfill here : https://github.com/github/fetch. 
I don't know if it's the best option to deal with my problem, but it works.

Comment: hm maybe you should use the fetch api, or build a service that would execute the request on the server side

Comment: @Sebas Yes I can make it work with a service but I want to avoid that. I tried with `fetch()`, and yes it works, but it's not supported on IE...

Comment: @Sebas I used a Polyfill for fetch to be compatible with IE and it works like a charm. Thank you :)